# Custom draw ComboBox to reduce size of arrow [C++ Builder XE/2]

Tags: custom-controls, c++builder, builder, vcl

I've got a string (horizontal) of drop down ComboBoxes. Considering the data in them is so small, the drop down arrow takes up a lot of space and makes the entire thing look ugly.

So I'm wondering about making the 'arrow' only turn on during mouse hover, or something similar. But I don't want other people to look at it and have their eyes bleed. I know, I know, there are reasons for UI standards, but this seems like an exception to me. I'm assuming that if someone wants to change the data, they'll at least hover the mouse over it, if not click it.

Target is C++ Builder XE2, but Visual C++ targeted examples are fine too. I don't expect a full working example, just a push in the right direction (unless of course there is a fully working component out there already waiting for drag and drop, no point reinventing in that case)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing what you consider to be "ugly"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any control over the drop-down arrow.  It is part of the underlying ComboBox window that is managed by the OS, not the VCL.

What I would suggest you do is use `TEdit` instead of `TComboBox`, and then create a separate `TForm` that has a `TListBox` on it.  When the user hovers over a `TEdit` or clicks on it, you can display the `TForm` and update its `TListBox` to contain the relavant items.  If the user clicks on an item in the `TListBox`, you can assign that string value to the current `TEdit`.  This gives you more control over the look-and-feel of the `TListBox` display, give you more controls over its on-screen positioning, maybe even add some special effects like fade-in/out via the `TForm.AlphaBlend` property, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of something similar, which I'll put below. Why the TForm? Dynamically creating objects is quite simple and doesn't carry the complexities of trying to line up an entire form?

Answer (score 0):

Use a TLabel instead of a TEdit (as the user never needs to edit it directly) and when the user hovers over the label, it shows a TComboBox in exactly the same position so it becomes obvious you can click on it. The TComboBox is hidden once the mouse is outside of the area, showing just the label.

Or, have an TEdit which I show the arrow on myself, and show a TListBox when clicked (very similar to the answer posted above, but without the form)